# ¿Pór qué me dice que no encuentra un archivo index, si no le hago una peticion de este archivo?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, handlebars.js, filesystem

Recién aprendo a empaquetar aplicaciones de NodeJS con pkg, todo ha ido bien, en teoria, sin embargo hay una ruta que no entiendo porque falla.

---

[image: Vista de archivos que se encuentran en la carpeta de moonp]

Bien, esto es una pagina que se ve desde el navegador, y la aplicacion envia esta información, desde el código se administra toda esa logistica, incluso el poder visualizar la miniatura de la imagen (esos 2 archivos son imagenes), sin embargo cuando se hace la petición de la imagen para ponerla de miniatura, el "servidor" marca como 404 y ademas pone un error de `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\ACER\moonp\index.html'` y bueno, no sé.

**Código de `get /moon`**

```js
router.get('/moon', (req, res) => {
    
        var files = [];
        fs.readdir(fileFolderm, (err, filess) => {
            
            filess.forEach(file => {
                var stats = fs.statSync(fileFolderm+file)
                if (stats["size"] < 100000) {
                    var fileSize = stats["size"] + " Bytes";
                } else {
                    var fileSize = (stats["size"] / 1000000.0).toFixed(2) + " MB";
                }

                files.push({name: file, dpath: '/viewmoonp/'+ file, path: "/mdownload/" + file, size: fileSize});
            })
            
        })
        
        res.render('index', { filelist: files, moon: true})
    
    })
```

Sea `dpath` el enlace que se envia para que el navegador solicite la imagen de miniatura.

**y este el codigo de cuando se solicita `/viewmoonp/:id`**

```js
router.get('/viewmoonp/:id', (req, res) => {
        let filereq = req.params.id;
        
        if (fs.existsSync(fileFolderm + filereq)) {
            res.sendFile(fileFolderm, filereq)
        } else {
            res.render('download', { error : true, message : 'File not found', requested : req.params.id })
        }
    })
```

Siendo `:id` la imagen que solicita.

Al hacer la petición de `/moon`se carga la página de index normal, pero se envian los archivos de la carpeta de moonp, funciona bien. Pero cuando el navegador solicita las imagenes para cargar la miniatura, es decir `/viewmoonp/:id`, la consola marca error 404, además de que aparéce como si hubiese buscado un archivo index.html ahí mismo

```
GET /moon 200 8.244 ms - 3735
GET /viewmoonp/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-11-09%20at%205.46.10%20PM(1).jpeg 404 2.657 ms - 214
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\ACER\moonp\index.html'
GET /viewmoonp/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-11-07%20at%206.15.54%20PM.jpeg 404 1.601 ms - 214
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\ACER\moonp\index.html'
```

Lista de archivos en carpeta:
[image: Carpeta de moonp con los archivos]

---

Ademas, el enlace de descarga si funciona bien, no creo que aporte mucho, pero lo comparto:

```js
router.get('/mdownload/:id', (req, res) => {
        if (fs.existsSync(fileFolderm+ req.params.id)) {
            res.download(fileFolderm+ req.params.id)
        } else {
            res.render('download', { error : true, message : 'File not found', requested : req.params.id })
        }
        
    })
```

La variable `fileFolderm` tiene el valor `C:/Users/ACER/moonp/`

Se estan utilizando los paquetes:

```js
const express = require('express');
var colors = require('colors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileUpload');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

El error estaba en la linea donde se envia el archivo que se solicita.

```
router.get('/viewmoonp/:id', (req, res) => {
        let filereq = req.params.id;
        
        if (fs.existsSync(fileFolderm + filereq)) {
            res.sendFile(fileFolderm, filereq)
        } else {
            res.render('download', { error : true, message : 'File not found', requested : req.params.id })
        }
    })
```

El error se encontraba en que el "archivo" que se enviaba era la variable `fileFolderm` con el comentario o mensaje que era el nombre del archivo, lo cual no servia, porque el navegador hacia la solicitud de fileFolderm + lo que busca principalmente "index.html".

He cambiado la linea

```
res.sendFile(fileFolderm, filereq)
```

Por:

```
res.sendFile(fileFolderm + filereq)
```

Y nuevamente el servidor envia la imagen que se solicita, permitiendo así que se pueda visualizar la miniatura.

Moraleja: xD hay que saber donde poner comas para unir variables.

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readdir` es asincrono, y por tanto la última linea se manda antes de que obtengas los ficheros

```js
router.get('/moon', (req, res) => {

  var files = [];
  fs.readdir(fileFolderm, (err, filess) => {
    //Debemos esperar a que termine de cargar las 
    //carpetas para obtener las minuaturas. 
    filess.forEach(file => {
      var stats = fs.statSync(fileFolderm + file)
      if (stats["size"] < 100000) {
        var fileSize = stats["size"] + " Bytes";
      } else {
        var fileSize = (stats["size"] / 1000000.0).toFixed(2) + " MB";
      }

      files.push({
        name: file,
        dpath: '/viewmoonp/' + file,
        path: "/mdownload/" + file,
        size: fileSize
      });
    })
    // Enviamos la respuesta 
    res.render('index', {
      filelist: files,
      moon: true
    })

  })

  //ESTA LINEA LA MOVEMOS
  //res.render('index', {
  //  filelist: files,
  //  moon: true
  //})

})
```

Te buscaba un index por que viewmoon no recibía los parametros que necesitaba.